# Access 25%, 50%, 75% Quartiles (Data From Query and Result Destination is a Report)

Tags: vba, ms-access, quartile

The data that I need the quartiles is a query with the first column being the month-year and the second column being a count of defects for that month. I am looking to have the quartiles to be displayed on a report (Name: QE Quartile Test).

Query name: QE Test Count Step 2
Columns names: ProductionYM ; Claims

The following code is something I found online but I don't code much so I don't know where to go from here.

```
Public Function XPercentile()
    XPercentile = DMin(Claims, QETest, "DCount(""*"", """ & QETest & """, """ & Claims & "<="" & [" & Claims & " ]) >= " & 0.5 * DCount("*", QETest))
End Function
```

I am aware that excel has all the functions to do this but I was requested to get this to work in access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find that here on **GitHub**: [VBA.Quartiles](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Quartiles)

***Calculate quartiles in 20 ways and medians in Microsoft Access***

Code is way to much to post here, but included is also a link to the full documentation:

[20 Varieties of Quartiles](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33718/20-Varieties-of-Quartiles.html)

(if you don't have an account, browse for the link: Read the full article)